# Moving div don´t stops onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make an animation of 2 div´s but I don´t succeed :(.

I want the DIV Tablou to move left and the DIV Frame1, Frame2, etc... to appear but every time I click on my links the Tablou DIV moves left. 
So far I succeed with the frames to appear and the DIV Tablou move left.

The question is: how can I make the DIV Tablou move left and stay there and when I click on Close button to move right to his original position??
Many thanks

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="tablou"  onclick="move_left()">
  <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="menu">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:show('frame1');" class="categories">Main</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:show('frame2');" class="categories">About Us</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

```
<div name="frames" id="frame1"> Frame 1 </div>

<div name="frames" id="frame2"> Frame 2 </div>
```

**The script that I am using:**

```
function show(currentframe) {
     $('div[name|="frames"]').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == currentframe) {
               $(this).show(200);      
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide(600);
          }
     });
}
function move_left() {
    $('#tablou').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "-=250px"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function `show` you have to stop the event from bubbling, bu you can't do that as long as you're attaching event listeners like that. Use something more modern, and since I see you're using jQuery try something like this:

HTML code:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="main" class="categories">Main</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="aboutus" class="categories">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#main").click(function(e) {
    // This prevents that the event bubbles up to #tablou
    e.stopPropagation();
    // This prevents that clicking on the link adds # to the url
    e.preventDefault();
    show("frame1");
});
$("#aboutus").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    show("frame2");
});
```

Comment: For compatibility with IE: add `e = e || window.event`, then `if (!(e.preventDefault)){ e.returnValue = false; e.cancelBubble = true; } else { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();}`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I don't usually use jQuery, but IIRC jQuery "fixes" the event object adding those methods. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Thank you very much. I inserted the code and is working fine.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: It works very well in IE8, IE7. Tested by me right now.

Comment: @MaxArt: yes. your answer was exactly what I need it. thank you very much again.

Comment: @MoraruBogdan So put the check mark on my answer, clicking on it right below the vote counter. I see you're a newbie, maybe you don't know how to do it?

Comment: jQuery uses event delegation, so in reply to maxart: yes, it irons out most of the cross browser bumps one might encounter otherwise. In fact, returning false in a jQuery event handler amounts to the same thing as `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()`. It's important to know that this doesn't stand when not using jQuery, though, returning false then will still allow the event to bubble up